# SIGALRM not terminating a program after the specified time

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I have written a C code, where the aim is to take N as an input and then create N processes and create some children of their own. Each process sends signals from i+1th process to i+12th process(doesn't matter if it exists or not) the SIGUSR1 signal. If a process doesn't receive any signal by any process, you exit the process. The idea is to close all the process after 10 seconds using SIGALRM but the program doesn't terminate. If a take N as an input through command line, the program works but if taken through scanf, it somehow breaks. TIA

```
static int signal_receive = 0;

void sighandler(int signum){       //////////signal handler for SIGUSR1 signal
  signal_receive++;
}

int main(void){

  int n;
  printf("enter N - ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int id1 = 1, id2 = 1;    //////// ids for tracking the process
  for(int i = 0; i<n; ++i){
    if(id1>0 && id2>0){     /////// only the grandparent can enter
      id1 = fork();
      int z = getpid()%13;
      for(int j = 0; j<z; ++j){
        if(id2>0 && id1==0)          //////// only the parent can enter
          id2 = fork();
      }
    }
  }

  alarm(10);          ///////// alarm for 10 seconds after which process stops sending SIGUSR1 and exits

  while(1){                       /////// SIGUSR1 signal
    sleep(2);
    for(int i = 1; i<13; ++i)
      kill(getpid()+i, SIGUSR1);
      if(signal_receive==0){
         printf("signal exited %d\n", getpid());
      exit(0);
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i<n*13; ++i)
    wait(NULL);

}
```

Comment: Definite problems:  1.  [`fork()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) returns `pid_t`, not `int`. 2. You need to add `#include <unistd.h>` to use `fork()`  3.  You never set a signal handler with either `signal() or even better `sigaction()`  4.  `static int signal_receive = 0;` [needs to be `volatile sig_atomic_t` 5. `getpid()+i` makes no sense at all

Comment: the posted is failing to check (and handle) errors from when the call to `fork()` fails.  Note: a user process is only allowed to create a (very limited) number of children

Comment: regarding: `void sighandler(int signum){       //////////signal handler for SIGUSR1 signal
  signal_receive++;
}`  the parameter is not handled.  This will result in a message from the compiler about a 'unused parameter'.  This is not the only 'does not cleanly compile' problem in the code.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  it is missing the needed `#include` statements

Answer (score 1):

```
getpid()+i
```

how do you know that the i-th child has that pid? That a wrong assumption. You must store the pids in a table and use it to kill the corresponding processes. Something like:

```
pid_t pids[...];
int n;

...
id = fork();
if (id!=0) pids[n++] = id; // store the new pid in the array
...


...
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   kill(pids[i],SIGUSR1); // get pids from array and kill them
...
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear with the question. Each process sends signal to i+1th process to i+12th process(doesn't matter if it exists or not)  the SIGUSR1 signal. If a process doesn't receive any signal by any process, you exit the process. I have made some edits to the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @johnny_bravo `getpid()+i` means nothing! When you fork a new pid is returned to the caller giving you the pid of the child, but the pid of the chil has nothing to do with the pid of the father, there is no relation caller_pid+i for the i-th child! Don't do this. Like I said, store pids somewhere first.